# x264: ignore empty options in bash script

Tags: bash, variables, x264

I do some video encoding using a script with x264. Most options follow the pattern

```
x264 --option0 $value0 --option1 $value1 -o output.file input.file
```

The script reads the values from a text file. The text file contains key-values like `crf=18.3`. Unfortunately, this does not work for mb-tree, as the option does not have a $value, it is set by default and can be turned off with `--no-mbtree`.

If `mbtree=no-mbtree` is set in the text file, everything works fine. But if I choose to encode with mbtree turned on, the `--$variable-for-mb-tree-or-no-mb-tree` is still in place, but unset or empty and x264 throws an error.

How can I tell bash/ x264 to ignore an unset or empty variable? I'd like to avoid an if…then…else and rather do it inline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use alternate values in parameter expansion:

```
mycommand ${myvar:+ "--$myvar"}
```

If `myvar=foo`, this will run `mycommand --foo`

If `myvar` is unset or empty, it will run `mycommand` with no flags.

Comment: Great, thank you, @that-other-guy! I guess the answer is not completely correct or I partly misunderstood the answer: If `myvar`is empty, that is `myvar=` in the mentioned text file, the command is run. But if the variable isn't there at all, e.g. an empty line, `mycommand` runs with no flags.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you give an example of what you want to run when 1. `myvar=foo`, 2. `myvar=`, and 3. there is no myvar= line?

Comment: Now the script includes this:
`#!/bin/bash`
`config="path/to/cfg"`(…)
`while IFS='=' read lhs rhs; do`
`if [[ ! $lhs =~ ^\ *# && -n $lhs ]]; then`
` rhs="${rhs%%\#*}"  # del in line right comments`
` rhs="${rhs%"${rhs##*[^ ]}"}" # del trailing spaces`
` rhs="${rhs%\"*}"  # del opening string quotes`
` rhs="${rhs#\"*}"  # del closing string quotes`
` declare $lhs="$rhs"`
` fi`
`done < "$config"`
`(…)`
`wine "$winedir"/drive_c/Program\ Files/avs2yuv/avs2yuv.exe` "${avs##*=}" - \`
`| x264 --stdin y4m ${nombtree:+ "--no-mbtree"} \`
`--option0 "$value0" \`
`-o output.file -`

Comment: The lenghty script refers to a configuration file, which contains one parameter each line:
`crf=18.6
aqs=0.75
(…)`

The default for mb-tree is on, the parameter to turn it off is `--no-mbtree`.

"3. there is no myvar= line"
I run the script without any values, like with an empty line in the cfg and as expected:
`mediainfo output.file
(…) mbtree=1 (…)`

"myvar=foo"
I run the script with
`nombtree=--no-mbtree` in config file:
`mediainfo output.file
(…) mbtree=0 (…)`

"2. myvar="
But if I run the script with
`nombtree=` in config file:
`mediainfo output.file
(…) mbtree=0 (…)`

Comment: Sorry for the mess, I do not cope with formatting here, and editing time is always eaten up before I get it. Last example behaves different than predicted.

Comment: I mean, can you give it in terms of the command you want to run? I'm assuming `mediainfo output.file (…) ` is not part of the `x264` command. For example, `mbtree=--no-mbtree` should run `x264 .. --no-mbtree`, while `mbtree=` (empty) should run `x264 ..` (i.e. no mb-tree related flags)?

Comment: mediainfo reads the output.file and tells, if mbtree is turned on or off for the encoding.

there is no myvar= line / empty line: 
`x264 --option0 $value0 (…)` , here no --no-mbtree flag.    
     
myvar=foo / nombtree=--no-mbtree,   `x264 --option0 $value0 --no-mbtree (…)`  
here --no-mbtree flag is set.    
     
myvar= / nombtree=   
`x264 --option0 $value0 (…)`     
here --no-mbtree flag is set also but it shouldn't.

Comment: the bashism works as you described. I messed up my mind with to many no's and negations. thanks for your help. I should read more man bash.